# How to implement a Query with IQueryable in SilverLight

Tags: linq, silverlight, iqueryable

I have two tables customers, pay and want to implement a gridview in silverlight with the outcome of the relationship of these two tables, the query is as follows

```
SELECT     Pa.Tipo_Pagare, Pa.Pagare, Pa.Rut, Cli.Nombre
FROM         Cred_Crexsa.dbo.Pagare AS Pa INNER JOIN
                  Cred_Crexsa.dbo.Clientes AS Cli ON Pa.Rut = Cli.Rut
WHERE     (Pa.Nulo <> 0) AND (Pa.Extraviado <> 0)
```

Thank you very much 
Leonardo Moreno Flores

Comment: Did you have a question?  Is there something you are having difficulty with?

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight doesn't have any DB libraries.  You'll need to write a webservice.  Either reconstruct the query on the web server using your ORM of choice (many of them now support LINQ features, if you prefer) or have it call a stored procedure based on the SQL you posted.